# Opera extension to open a file

Tags: javascript, opera, opera-extension

My problem is simple. Is there a way to open an external file already saved in the computer via Opera extension? I know that normally in javascript on the web it's not possible dues to safety but isn't the extension local?

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Open from where? From your OS, from that extension that saved it, from an arbitrary webpage?

Comment: Can you show us the code that saved the file, and what you have tried to open it?

Comment: Yea open from somewhere in my PC. I would like to use an .exe file that would do some stuff that I cannot handle with js.
I would place the file along with the extension somewhere so there's no need to download it. I tried window.open but that doesn't work.

Comment: So you want to write an extension that contains a `.exe` which can be executed by the user manually?

Comment: :D actually I would like to make an extension that can execute that .exe file. For example user activates the extension in the browser and therefore the .exe file automatically starts.

Comment: Sounds like you want to program a plugin instead. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Mmmm well maybe but I think Opera devs provide support for extensions so I wanted to use that. I wanna use some winapi which I cannot really access via js only.

Comment: Which Opera version are you targeting, btw? With the switch to blink, afair a lot has changed: http://dev.opera.com/extensions/

Comment: Opera Next or normal one that's not important. Of course the newest version.

Comment: See [here](https://rawgit.com/operasoftware/devopera-static-backup/master/http/dev.opera.com/articles/view/the-opera-plug-in-interface/index.html) or [here](https://rawgit.com/operasoftware/devopera-static-backup/master/http/dev.opera.com/addons/extensions/index.html) for the old docs. For Opera Next, [extension are basically Chrome extensions](http://dev.opera.com/extensions/index.html).

Comment: Thanks but I've already seen them. This is a problem that I cannot solve though :D
I know the basic structure etc the only thing left to me is that connection with the .exe file which I have a feeling would be impossible :-(

Comment: I think you need a plugin for that. An extension is basically just an add-on, with extended rights to access browser internals. It's not native, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. That would be harder than I thought :D

Comment: Think about the possibilities for malicious extensions if what you're asking for (executing an arbitrary .exe file) were possible... there are good reasons you can't do that. ;-)

Comment: Yea I thought so but on the other hand the devs can check every extension before publishing.